# windows service running tasks on different timers

Tags: c#, windows, service

I have a windows service which I need to do 2 things, one every 15 minutes and one once per day.  is it valid to do this with 2 timers, something like what I have below?

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("start");
    this.regularTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(300000D);
    this.regularTimer.AutoReset = true;
    this.regularTimer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(this.DoRegular);
    this.regularTimer.Start();

    this.longTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(86400000D);
    this.longTimer.AutoReset = true;
    this.longTimer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(this.DoLongRunning);
    this.longTimer.Start();
}
```

Comment: " is it valid to do this with 2 timers" yes.

Comment: Have you considered just using the windows task scheduler for this? Bear in mind that your "once per day" timer will fire on 24 hours intervals after each service restart - so if the service is restarted on a number of successive days, but at earlier times each day, that could postpone the running of the "once per day" activity for several entire days.

Comment: I might do, just wanted confirmation that I could indeed use 2 timers simultaneously in the one service.  I was thinking of separating them into 2 but would rather keep them in the one service, thanks

Comment: It might make more sense to manually set the interval on the 24-hour timer calculated as the top me until the next 24-hour cycle. For example, if it's meant to fire at noon each day and the service is cycled at 10 am, the timer interval would be set to 2 hours. Then, instead of autoreset = true, a new interval to the next 24-hour time point is calculated from within the elapsed handler.